# PyQt5 - ao abrir uma janela a partir de um arquivo importado, as Widgets não aparecem

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt-5, import

A partir do QtDesigner, em uma MainWindow, adicionei dois RadioButtons. Gerei o arquivo python (.py). Executando diretamente deu tudo certo. Mas quando chamo o arquivo gerado de um arquivo principal, os radiobuttons não aparecem! Alguém poderia me ajudar nesse problema? Para gerar o arquivo principal, utilizei o Pycharm. Testei tanto executando pelo PyCharm quanto diretamente pela IDLE do python 3.8. Não aparece nenhuma mensagem de erro. A seguir, repasso os dois códigos na integralidade:

_________*****************************main.py*****************************

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from problema import *

class Tela(QMainWindow):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Tela()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

____________*************************problema.py*************************

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow: object) -> object:
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(222, 113)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 10, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(50, 40, 82, 17))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 222, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "RadioButton"))

if __name__ == "___main___":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Bom dia! Criei uma solução paleativa modificando o arquivo principal. Conexões de signals e slots não vão funcionar dentro da classe, mas por fora a partir da instância "w". É o que consegui. Eis como o código ficou:

```
class Tela(QMainWindow):
    def __int__(self):
        super().__init__()
        # self.ui = Ui_MainWindow() - saiu daqui(1)
        # self.ui.setupUi(self) - saiu daqui(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)

    w = Tela()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow() #adicionei aqui(1)
    ui.setupUi(w) #adicionei aqui(2)
    w.show()

    exit(app.exec_())
```